How do I align the checkboxes and radio buttons, along with their labels, to the left side?
I have aligned all the other inputs in my form to the left side and i want to do the same with my radio buttons and check boxes. I am not understanding why they are centered since i don't think I have mentioned center alignment anywhere.
I have tried using float:left and flexbox but it did not work. It also messed up the alignment further. Please help me to align the radio buttons and checkboxes to look like this:
Example Form
My output currently looks like this:
My output
HTML CODE:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/forms/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Maths Tuition Registration Form</h1>
      <form action="">
        <div class="section">
          <label for="name">Name</label> <br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="section">
          <label for="email">Email</label> <br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email id" />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <label for="gender">Gender</label> <br />
          <ul type="none">
            <li class="gender-span">
              <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" />
              <label for="male" class="gender-label">Male</label>
            </li>
            <br />
            <li class="gender-span">
              <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" />
              <label for="female" class="gender-label">Female</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="section">
          <label for="password">Password</label> <br />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password" />
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="Courses">
          <label for="">Courses</label><br />
          <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="algebra" />
            <label for="algebra" class="checkbox-label">Algebra</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="geometry" />
            <label for="geometry" class="checkbox-label">Geometry</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="trignometry" />
            <label for="trignometry" class="checkbox-label">Trigonometry</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="calculus" />
            <label for="calculus" class="checkbox-label">Calculus</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>


CSS CODE:
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

div {
  background-color: #282A3A;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: #C69749;
}

label {
  color: #C69749;
}

input {
  background-color: #1C1E2C;
  color: #C69749;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #C69749;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.section {
  margin: 0.01px;
}

.gender-label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  float: left;
}

.divcheck {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px; /* Added margin to separate checkboxes */
}

.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: left; */
}

